# Не получается импортировать модуль pygame mac os

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pygame

Как установить модуль pygame чтобы он работал с python 3.4 на mac os?

Пробовал [вот эту инструкцию](http://pygame.org/wiki/macintosh), но ругается ответом 404 на команду

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Скачал python 2.7 установил с офф сайта pygame, попытался перекинул папку pygame из site-packages python 2.7 в аналогичную папку python 3.4 - при запуске ругается на:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/smosker/PycharmProjects/untitled/23.py", line 2, in <module>
import games
File "/Users/smosker/PycharmProjects/untitled/games.py", line 57, in <module>
import pygame, pygame.image, pygame.mixer, pygame.font,  pygame.transform 
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
from pygame.base import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/base.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pygame/base.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
```

Как корректно установить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, вот верная инструкция (последовательно вводим строки в terminal.app, дожидаемся пока отработает и вводим следующую):

```bash
xcode-select --install
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Install Pygame

```bash
brew install mercurial
brew install git
brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_mixer sdl_ttf portmidi
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```